# Is there a query in MySQL that would allow variable group numbers and limits akin to this

Tags: mysql, group-by

I've checked out a few of the stackoverflow questions and there are similar questions, but didn't quite put my fingers on this one.

If you have a table like this:

```
uid    cat_uid    itm_uid
 1        1          4
 2        1          5
 3        2          6
 4        2          7
 5        3          8
 6        3          9
```

> where the uid column in auto_incremented and the cat_uid references a
>   category of relevance to filter on and the itm_uid values are the one
>   we're seeking

I would like to get a result set that contains the following sample results:

```
array (
 0 => array (1 => array(4,5)),
 1 => array (2 => array(6,7)),
 2 => array (3 => array(8,9))
)
```

An example issue is - select 2 records from each category (however many categories there may be) and make sure they are the last 2 entries by uid in those categories.

I'm not sure how to structure the question to allow an answer, and any hints on a method for the solution would be welcome!

**EDIT:**
This wasn't a very clear question, so let me extend the scenario to something more tangible.

I have a set of records being entered into categories and I would like to select, with as few queries as possible, the latest 2 records entered per category, so that when I list out the contents of those categories, I will have at least 2 records per category (assuming that there are 2 or more already in the database).  A similar query was in place that selected the last 100 records and filtered them into categories, but for small numbers of categories with some being updated faster than others can lead to having the top 100 not consisting of members from every category, so to try to resolve that, I was looking for a way to select 2 records from each category (or N-records assuming it's the same per-category) and for those 2 records to be the last entered.  A date field is available to sort on, but the itm_uid itself could be used to indicate inserted order.

Comment: It is not too clear what you actually want to do, but maybe have a look at the MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

Comment: I've extended my initial question with a scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT cat_uid, itm_uid,
   IF( @cat = cat_uid, @cat_row := @cat_row + 1, @cat_row := 0 ) AS cat_row,
   @cat := cat_uid
   FROM my_table
   JOIN (SELECT @cat_row := 0, @cat := 0) AS init
   HAVING cat_row < 2
   ORDER BY cat_uid, uid DESC
```

You will have two extra columns in the results, just ignore them.

This is the logic:

We sort the table by cat_uid, uid descending, then we start from the top and give each row a "row number" (cat_row) we reset this row number to zero whenever cat_uid changes:

```
---------------------------------------
|  uid  | cat_uid | itm_uid | cat_row |
|   45  |    4    |    34   |    0    |
|   33  |    4    |    54   |    1    |
|   31  |    4    |    12   |    2    |
|   12  |    4    |    51   |    3    |
|   56  |    6    |    11   |    0    |
|   20  |    6    |    64   |    1    |
|   16  |    6    |    76   |    2    |
|  ...  |   ...   |   ...   |    ...  |
---------------------------------------
```

now if we keep only the rows that have `cat_row < 2` we get the results we want:

```
---------------------------------------
|  uid  | cat_uid | itm_uid | cat_row |
|   45  |    4    |    34   |    0    |
|   33  |    4    |    54   |    1    |
|   56  |    6    |    11   |    0    |
|   20  |    6    |    64   |    1    |
|  ...  |   ...   |   ...   |    ...  |
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you explain the @-sign and thr :=-sign? Why Having cat_row < 2?

Comment: @Jitamaro `@cat_row` is a variable, `:=` is the operator that assigns a value to a variable, `cat_row < 2` because you wanted to "select **2** records from each category".

Comment: @Jitamaro And why all this trouble? Because there is no such thing as "limit per group" in MySql.

Comment: Thanky you, I suggest a simplier solution. Is your solution gives exact copy of OP questions?

Comment: Yes, it's much trouble, I don't understand it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement the solution based on the solution from 'nobody', but I think this provides with hints and clues as to how, which is what I was looking for, rather than the solution itself, so I'm going to accept this answer and invite any additional clarifications to make this answer more authoritative if you can?

Comment: @MyStream If you have a question just ask, I'll try to help.

Comment: @nobody, I'm unsure what's happening because I'm not up on the operators in the query example you've provided.  Perhaps, if you could add a note about what the operators are doing in the context of the above it would be more than adequate to explain the logic you've used for it and help me understand the way to approach it better?

Comment: @nobody - that's a brilliant illustration - very clear :) In referencing the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/user-variables.html it take some lateral thinking from the comments to see how this would apply to different situations, but your edited example above makes it much clear how this could be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is called an adjacent tree model or a parent-child tree model. It's one of the simplier tree model where there is only 1 pointer or 1 leaf. You would solve your query with a recursion or using a Self Join. Sadly MySQL doesn't support recursive queries, maybe it's working with prepared statements. I want to suggest you an Self Join. With a Self Join you can get all the rows from the right side and the left side with a special condition.

```
select t1.cat_uid, t2.cat_uid, t1.itm_uid, t2.itm_uid From t1 Inner Join t2 On t1.cat_uid = t2.cat_uid
```

Comment: Hi Jitamaro, I'm not sure how you'd limit the sets here, can you expand on this please?

Comment: Thank you for attempting this one - I think it requires an approach along the lines as the one above - perhaps a wiki on operator use with examples will help boost the mysql resource, which isn't terribly transparent: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/user-variables.html

Comment: No problem, I'm new to complex SQL scripting, it doesn't look very user friendly.